# Passed data lost in Laravel paginator starting from page 2

Tags: laravel, paginator

I am trying to list people by their appRole. Here's the controller:

```
public function indexByAppRole(Request $request, $appRoleId)
{
    $h1 = AppRole::where('id', $appRoleId)->first()->name;

    return view('admin.people.index', [
        'people' => $this->people->byAppRole($appRoleId),
        'appRoles' => $this->appRoles->forAll(),
        'h1'     => 'Role: '. $h1,
    ]);
}
```

Paginator is used in the repository:

```
public function byAppRole($appRoleId)
{
    return Person::where('person_app_role.app_role_id', $appRoleId)
    ->join('person_app_role', 'person_app_role.person_id', '=', 'people.id')
    ->select('people.*')    // fix ID confusion but why?
    ->paginate(20);
}
```

The main view lists the returned people. In the sidebar, I have the following list as side-navigation:

```
<ul class="list-group nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    @foreach ($appRoles as $appRole)
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('admin.people.appRole', ['appRoleId' => $appRole->id]) }}">{{ str_plural($appRole->name) }}</a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
</ul>
```

The navigation list works on page 1 of search results or listings, but the list is not showing up on page 2 and subsequent pages. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why you dont use `Paginate`. Here are the example [http://tutsnare.com/how-to-create-pagination-in-laravel/]

 Also see Laravel documentation.
[https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination]

Comment: @Manish I did use Paginate in the repository. I revised the text to reflect this.

Comment: What do the link to page 2 looks like? It can be that it is missing some get parameter. If you use get parameters to get page 1 you might have to use `paginate(20)->appends('your get paramters)` to get a correct link to page 2

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. For AppRole, I also used a paginator, so this was fixed by using `all()` instead of `paginate()` to get all appRoles.

```
// Before...........
public function forAll()
{
    return AppRole::paginate(20);
}
```

And:

```
// After............
public function forAll()
{
    return AppRole::all();
}
```